# How to debug a flask-restful api with pdb

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, pdb

I want to use pdb to step into some flask-restful code. I have an endpoint which returns a token. I then use the token to access another endpoint which returns the required data. I would like to view the result of a database query. How do I go about this?

I tried setting a breakpoint inside the class, but it does not get triggered when I send a request using the request library.

```
class FetchData(Resource):

    @jwt_required
    def get(self, args):

        engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://')
        conn = engine.connect()

        tablemeta = MetaData()
        tablemeta.reflect(bind=engine)

        keydate = tablemeta.tables['KEYDATE']
        coefficient = tablemeta.tables['COEFFICIENT']
        vessel = tablemeta.tables['VESSEL']
        update_dict = {}


        s = select([coefficient])
        s = s.where(coefficient.c.updated_date >= args["dt"])
        rp = conn.execute(s)

        result = []

        for r in rp:
            j = coefficient.join(vessel, r['idvessel'] == vessel.c.idvessel)

            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()
            vdm_id = select([vessel.c.vessel_id]).select_from(j)
            vdm_id = conn.execute(vdm_id).scalar()

            intermediate = []
            intermediate.append({"vdm_id": vdm_id})
            intermediate.append([dict(r)])

            result.append(intermediate)
```

Or possibly there's another debugger I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your `pdb` before the loop as it will never get to `pdb` if you don't get any results.

I have been using `pdb` for the last few years in `flask` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just use print(variable-you-want), this should be faster and efficient.